# What is the difference between these 3 type assignments in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

Is there any difference in assigning a function return type (especially never) in TypeScript? For some reason, `cf` is behaving differently among others.

```js
let a: string | undefined
let b: string | undefined
let c: string | undefined

const af = () => {
    throw new Error()
}
const bf = (): never => {
    throw new Error()
}
const cf: () => never = () => {
    throw new Error()
}

type testAF = ReturnType<typeof af>
//   ^? type testAF = never
type testBF = ReturnType<typeof bf>
//   ^? type testBF = never
type testCF = ReturnType<typeof cf>
//   ^? type testCF = never


if (!a) af();
a.length // 'a' is possibly 'undefined'

if (!b) bf();
b.length // 'b' is possibly 'undefined'

if (!c) cf();
c.length // No error
```

**TypeScript playground:**
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwgVzQBMQAzdEQgKFEgCM5FVMd8jTyqaIBjB5dLLgLEyaCpUrcA9mkTQSEALwQAFAEolAPggBvShAMQwACyRSA7hDGWAokjNJ1lAL6SZc2guXq4YgG4gSFq6+oYmZpbWEHYOTq7SspDcJHDqwf6BSqoaitp6hkamFlYgtvZSjmouEmAAngAOIEYgiACCAGJZAErgeEhoACoNIAA8dY1SClAkmpQA9HOGAHoA-JTjTWAtYABCnco9YH2Dw2PDkxCeswvLaxvNiADC+xCHx0ONZxMKydeLBqsJJQUAoVABCKAaabqADclCgADpQJgTBIQaowbQNJ5YZRaEiQCjjBA0aCwdwNMlcdwCUSIEA

Comment: ① Please include your relevant code as plain text here; a playground is nice but isn't enough by itself.  Specifically if you say "behaving differently" the code text should demonstrate that. ② https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695, the last one is fully annotated and is treated specially in control flow analysis.  Does that fully address the question? if so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate target; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, your answer is comprehensive enough. Thank you